# Identifying tracked javascript event to the right div

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am using plotly charts and have event triggered based on selection in the chart.

https://plot.ly/javascript/zoom-events/

So, in this example, there is one div on the page and a plotly chart is rendered. When i make a selection in the chart, the plotly_relayout event is fired. On this event, I am popping an alert that shows the event data.

My question is this: Suppose there were two divs on screen myDiv1 and myDiv2 both containing different charts.

When I make selection in one chart, the event fires and alert shows the event data.  Along with the event data, how can I also add information about from which div/chart the event was fired?

Thank you,
Asanas

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this functionality isn't baked into plotly.js events and you'll have to add this to your click handlers yourself. E.g.

```js
var plot1; // let's assume these are the plotly plots for now
var plot2;

plot1.on('plotly_click', function(e){
    myHandler('plot1', e);
});

plot2.on('plotly_click', function(e){
    myHandler('plot2', e);
});

function myHandler(id, e){
    console.log('Click data from ' + id + ':', e); 
}
```

Comment: This will solve my problem. Thank you! There's one more thing that's troubling me. Suppose my page had many charts and I wanted to bind one function to all those charts, how would I do that? Suppose each of those divs have a class name and an id. Then I can have one function and bind it to all divs using the class name. But in that case, I am back to the same problem as to which div got clicked. How will I get the div id of that div? Any example will be greatly helpful.

Comment: In the scenario you've provided, you'll still have access to the DOM elements in your custom handler - you could select all the plots using their class names, then within your handler, you can use the id of the given element however you need - e.g. `node.id` where `node` is one of the nodes returned by a call like `document.getElementsByClassName('application-graph')`.